# Split multi-line text in columns

Tags: excel, regex, google-sheets

Given:

> 1. Confessionalized Optics: The Society of Jesus and Early Modern Optics
>
> Author: Purkaple, Brent
>
> University: University of Oklahoma
>
> Year Published: 2022
>
> Abstract:
>
> This dissertation explores the investigation and explanation of optics
> among prominent members of the Society of Jesus during the early
> modern period. In doing so it aims to explain why it was that optics
> became one of the more important scientific subjects among the members
> of the Order. In addition to this it aims to explain how it was that
> their identity as members of the Order shaped their explanation of
> optics at a time when there was no agreed upon meaning of optics. As
> argued, this interaction between Jesuit identity and optical theory
> may best be understood as an act of confessionalization. The benefit
> of this categorization is that it allows for a complex analysis of
> optics among the Society of Jesus which avoids any essential
> identification of the relationship between science and religion. This
> dissertation, then, not only addresses why optics among the Jesuits
> should be understood as confessionalized, but also how the category of
> confessionalization may provide a path through the complex dynamics of
> early modern science and religion.

I would like to have this (i.e. [hundreds of strings](https://brill.com/view/journals/jjs/9/4/article-p618_020.xml?Tab%20Menu=article) in this format) converted into a table with columns Number, Title, Author, University, Year Published, Abstract (multi-lines!).

I don't rely on a specific tool but I fail doing it with Excel. I think I will need to use a RegEx formula.

Comment: Excel is a spreadsheet, yet people have the tendency to use it as a database, although this is not what it is meant for. Why not opt for MS-Access for this purpose? After all, MS-Access has the `Long Text` data type, which is very well suited for this purpose.

Comment: fair point. However, the need to convert the text to columns in a table remains...And this is my issue in this post, I fear.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in power query. Some Abstracts where missing, for those I inserted an extra row manually in Excel.

Here you can watch how to do it in Power Query:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W_0tvPIOng

With the help of a formula I added new rows

[image]

One or two manual changes needed also.

Final outcome:
[image]

Here is a copy of that file:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkguU9IADpGxeeEOspPQ?e=KyF0oq